# How detect listview content changed completed?

Tags: android

What call after notifyDataSetChanged in adapter? What call after last getView in adapter? Has ListView  some post execute method after Listview content changed?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OnHierarchyChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener.html) will trigger when your listview's children are modified

Related question regarding view / childview children changes:
[Android - Listener/Callback for when number of View children changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605578/android-listener-callback-for-when-number-of-view-children-changes)